# struct Equality operator Immediate Window weird behaviour

Tags: c#, struct, operator-overloading, immediate-window

I'm doing some experiments with structs and operators, and I came across a situation that I cannot understand.

I have a struct that only contains an `int`. I've also implemteted 'implicit operator' methods so I can assign an `int` directly to it and I've implemented the Equality operators

Everything seems to be working fine at runtime, but if I make a breakpoint, and execute this `((TestStruct)1) == ((TestStruct)1);` in the Immediate Window it returns false, but at runtime it returns true (as I was expecting).

If I put another breakpoint, on the Equality operator, I can see that the code in there is being executed, but the values for my structs are not '1' as I was expecting, but some random ones.

Here is my sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool areEqual = ((TestStruct)1) == ((TestStruct)1);
        string breakPoint = ";)";
    }
}

struct TestStruct
{
    private Int32 value;
    public TestStruct(Int32 value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    static public implicit operator TestStruct(Int32 value)
    {
        return new TestStruct(value);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(TestStruct ptr1, TestStruct ptr2)
    {
        return ptr1.value == ptr2.value;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(TestStruct ptr1, TestStruct ptr2)
    {
        return ptr1.value != ptr2.value;
    }
}
```

**Edit** It seems to work fine if used with VS 2013, this issue seems to occur only with VS 2015

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: I copy pasted your example and cant reproduce.

Comment: I made that example with VS 2015, and with VS 2015 it doens't work for me..
I've tested now on VS 2013 and it works as expected..

Comment: I'm using VS2015 and it works.

Comment: Works in the 64-bit debugger, not in the 32-bit debugger.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.  VS2015 RTM has a significant number of bugs in the debug expression parser, connect.microsoft.com is the right place to report them.

Comment: I'll do that
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a Visual Studio 2015 bug as Hans Passant found out

Thanks ;)

Comment: Fixed in VS2015 Update 1, released at almost the exact same time you posted this answer :)